# Mostrar Temperatura de Bateria en TexrView

Tags: android-studio

!hola  ¿Cómo puedo mostrar la temperatura de la batería en un TextView?

```
package com.example.pc.programa;

import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView mos;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mos  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mostrar);
```

supuse que que de esta manera se obtenía la temperatura, y al mismo tiempo se mostraba.

```
    String temp = (BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE);
    mos.setText(temp);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma correcta de obtener la temperatura de la bateria en grados centigrados es

```
       int temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
       float temperatura = ((float) temp) / 10;
```

Pero este valor se obtiene a travez de un Intent por lo tanto para esto  debes crear un `BroadcastReceiver`, de acuerdo a tu codigo seria

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private float temperatura;
TextView mos;


    private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

            int temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
            float temperatura = ((float) temp) / 10;

            //Actualiza valor de temperatura en TextView.  
            mos.setText(String.valueOf(temperatura) + " °C");

        }
    };



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mos  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mostrar);

           //String temp = (BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE);

           this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));



        }
    }
```